# Adding custom function to doctrine query builder group by clause

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, group-by, query-builder

I want to group data by year and month of a date column using doctrine.
It currently uses the query builder to produce the statement which is working fine apart from the grouping.
I have installed the Month and Year custom functions from the Doctrine Extensions pack, however, I cannot do the following:

```
$qb->add('groupBy', 'MONTH(i.instdate)');
```

I get an Error: Cannot group by undefined identification variable message.

Is this possible with the query builder?
If not can I add DQL to a query builder result? What is the best way to do this?
I don't want to change the whole system to DQL as it is a query built from form options on the fly, so that would be a major change.

Comment: DQL and query builder are the same thing. The query builder simply assembles DQL.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround that you can use if you can add your custom function to your select clause. You can group by an alias of a custom function result that is in your select clause.

This would look like this

```
$qb->select('MONTH(i.instdate) as myMonth'....);
$qb->groupBy('myMonth');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that grouping by functions is not possible in the Doctrine version I am using.
It is available in later versions.

I decided to use SQL statments when this was required instead, as changing to a different version of Doctrine, inside ZF this close to a project completion would be too much.